# Can you initialize an STL container with unique_ptr from an initializer list?

Tags: c++11, stl, unique-ptr

I was wondering about this. Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::map< int, std::unique_ptr<int> > m =
    { { 1, std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(3)) } };

  return(0);
}
```

This is C++11. It fails to compile with a long ream of error messages on GCC, including one

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
>   { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
> ```

Is it possible at all to do what I'm trying to do here? I note that with shared_ptr, it works OK. Is it possible to do it with unique_ptr? If so, what am I missing? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The elements of an `initializer_list` cannot be modified.

The `unique_ptr` cannot be moved (because it's const) and it can't be copied (because it's a move-only type), so you're hosed.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I suspected something like that was going on -- "constexpr" seemed like a clue.

Comment: @mike4ty4 The real clue there, evidencing what Marshall said, is `use of deleted function [...] pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr]`. That is: this fails because it's a copy constructor, which will try to copy both elements, but of course, `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable. The move constructor would give you the same error if you managed to invoke that

Answer (score 1):

Sure, no problem.

First, a smart unique_ptr proxy, so we can create and move them around in a `const` context:

```
template<class T>
struct il_up {
  mutable std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int>* =nullptr
  >
  il_up( std::unique_ptr<U> o ): ptr(std::move(o)) {}

  operator std::unique_ptr<T>() const {
    return std::move(ptr);
  }
};
```

We then want to store this in an initializer_list.  Even though it is `const`, it can pass the `unique_ptr` out.

Then a container-making proxy to store the temporary initializer list:

```
template<class T>
struct make_container {
  std::initializer_list<T> il;
  make_container( std::initializer_list<T> const& l ):il(l) {} // const& here matters

  template<class C>
  operator C()&&{
    return {il.begin(), il.end()};
  }
};
```

and we are done:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec = make_container<il_up<int>>{
  std::make_unique<int>(1), std::make_unique<int>(2),
  std::make_unique<int>(3), std::make_unique<int>(4)
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b1389532c4124d9).

Comment: that is a smart workaround! proxy the unique_ptr! ;)